# Workaround to access protected attributes in derived friend class?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

In this MRE, I have a System that uses a state machine to control its internal state. Each state should access all attributes of the system for convenience.

My initial idea was to declare `SystemState` friend of `System`, however I am aware that friend relationship does not propagate to derived classes for security reasons. Here under, my `friend` keyword is therefore useless and I am not able to modify `system.foo` from `StateFoo`.

What can I change to this architecture to allow states of `System` access its protected attributes?

```
#include <vector>

// StateMachine.hpp
class StateBase {
    virtual void OnEnter() = 0;
};

class StateMachine {
    public:
        void AddState(const char *name, StateBase *state) {
            states.push_back(state);
        }

    private:
        std::vector<StateBase*> states;
};

// System.hpp
class System;

class SystemState : public StateBase {
    System &system;

    public:
        SystemState(System &system) : system(system) {}
};

class StateFoo : public SystemState {
    public:
    StateFoo(System &system) : SystemState(system) {}

    void OnEnter() override {
        SystemState::system.foo = 42;
    }
};

class System {
    StateMachine stateMachine;
    protected:
    int foo;

    public:
        System() : stateMachine() {
            stateMachine.AddState("foo", new StateFoo(*this));
        }

    friend class SystemState;
};
```

As suggested by [463035818-is-not-a-number](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4117728/463035818-is-not-a-number), I could make each attribute propagate like the example below, but in this case I would have to redeclare each of them twice.

```
class SystemState : public StateBase {
    System &system;
    protected:
        void set_foo(int f) { system.foo = f; }
    public:
        SystemState(System &system) : system(system) {}
};
```